# Nginx static files location block not working when added to nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

I'm having some trouble defining a rule to cache my static files. I've found this solution:

```
location ~* \.(ico|js|css|png|gif|jpe?g)$ {
  expires 7d;
}
```

which actually looks like what I need. The problem is, if I include this code into my NGINX.conf, no static files are delivered anymore and my site is blank. Any ideas/hints what might cause this result? Maybe I have to add, that the static files are distributed in different directories :/. My NGINX config file looks like this:

```
server {
  server_name               bla.domain.com;

  listen                    80;
  root                      /var/repo/;
                             
  location / {
    default_type            text/html;
    index                   index.html;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET)$ ) {
      return 444;
    }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* LWP::Simple|BBBike|wget) {
      return 403;
    }

    if ( $http_referer ~* (babes|forsale|girl|jewelry|love|nudit|organic|poker|porn|sex|teen) ) {
      return 403;
    }
  }

  location /bf/football/ {
    alias   /var/repos/f20;
  }

  location /bf/f20/ {
    alias   /var/repo/f20;
  }

  location /bf/zoo/ {
    alias   /var/repo/zoo/;
  }

  location /kbloader/ {
    alias   /var/repo/kbloader/;
  }
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me out with this or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Would you mind you post the complete configuration?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Put this before your other location block:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    access_log off;
}
```

That should work.

You could also use this:

```
## All static files will be served directly.
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
    ## fell swoop.
    tcp_nodelay off;

    ## Set the OS file cache.
    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
    open_file_cache_valid 45s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
}
```

Comment: How would one clear the cache in this instance?  Would it be as simple as restarting nginx?

Comment: This example is not a server side cache, it manages browser cache. You can clear browser cache by reloading with shift+F5 / ctrl+F5

Comment: if we update the static file on the server, will it update the new file immediately for the clients or we have to wait until it's expired ?

Comment: @nXqd You will have to wait until it expires. Use fingerprinting if you want to avoid that: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses

Comment: Another trick: In your HTML (template) you could use a query string to invalidate the browser cache.
    app/styles/style.css
would become 
    app/styles/style.css?v=1
Then whenever you update your CSS with new styles, you could invalidate it by changing it to
    app/styles/style.css?v=2

Comment: then which one is better ? your first code or the second ?

Comment: @sajad Depends on what you want to cache. Second one even caches xml and html. You do not always want to do that.

Comment: So which one is better? first one or the second?

Comment: NONE is better. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: If another block has definition for the static files with a root set, you should add the directives to that block

Comment: @JoostvanderLaan why adding the caching section if the static files are already being served directly?

Comment: what about gzip_static on;

Comment: both approaches makes that file types 404

Answer (score 29):

Put this before the server section in nginx config file as shown bellow:

```
. . .
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   expires $expires;
. . .
```

the ~image will handle all kind of images ( instead of hardcoding them )

for further informations on how to handle nginx caching see [link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/)

Comment: this answer should be selected as best. Thank you, @rachid

Comment: this does not handle webp wormat