# enable CACHE on nginx, CentOS 7

Tags: caching, nginx, static

I am new to nginx so sorry if this question has been asked before.

I am trying to enable cache on nginx. I found the solution [NGINX Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515132/nginx-cache-static-files)

The problem is that my nginx.conf which I have found in `/etc/nginx/ngin.conf` does not look anything like one posted there. So I am a bit confused and have no idea what to do.

here is my `nginx.conf`

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

so how should I apply the solution I have found or should I do something else?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` line at the bottom of your nginx.conf? This is where you'd symlink or save your actual host config files.. the ones you see in other posts, usually enclosed by `server {...}`.

You can change the path or add another one at any time and once nginx can successfully parse the included config files (`nginx -t` will test the files), you'd restart nginx gracefully using `nginx -s reload`

**UPDATE:**

Something like below would go into your filename.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /somewhere/on/your/machine;

    location / {
        expires 1d;
        # other caching related directives

        gzip            on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types      text/plain application/xml;
        # replace with your own gzip config

    }
}
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ for more detailed docs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already created one file for gzip purpose there, do I need to create another file for cache? and if I do then what do I have to enter into this file?

Comment: Thanks for this will give it a try and get back here in few minutes