# nginx cache not working for CSS and JS scripts when checking using curl command

Tags: nginx, caching

I'm trying to follow this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-ubuntu-16-04

but every time I execute curl -I http://myjsfile.com/thejsfile.js it doesn't return the cache property

i.e this one:

Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache

this is what I have in my sites-available file. though there are 2 in there the default and our custom one for Certbot SSL certs. I did apply this to those 2 files.

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    epoch;
}
```

So I'm not sure it's caching it and when I checked it using gtmetrix it still gets an F for browser caching.

I also tried this one: [NGINX cache static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515132/nginx-cache-static-files)

and I have this in my nginx.conf inside http

```
server {
        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
            access_log off;
        }
    }
```

but it still didn't work when I checked using the curl command.

so can someone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong here or is this not the best approach to cache JS and CSS files?